# Android ExpandableList Disable Groups

Tags: android, touch, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list with all groups always expanded and the groups not collapsable. The problem is that even if I made the groups to not collapse when I click on them the "select" effect is still visible and I don't want it to be visible. How can I do that?

Any answer would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out myself after all how to do that :D I have put this code:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

in the adapter of the ExpandableList in the getGroupView method. And now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you click on the group name, it collapses automatically. Here is an [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/) of expandableListView. Moreover, I could hardly make any comment unless I see what you did.